# Php session data wipes after two page redirections

Tags: php, https

I am making a payment processing system, using a PayPal API, and the issue is, that when I redirect the user to PayPal, I store a 'paypal_hash' inside the session, after information being entered into the PayPal system, the user is then redirected to the webpage, and the 'paypal_hash' is no longer there.
process_payment.php:

```
session_start();
$payment->create($api);

//Generate hash
$hash = md5($payment->getId()); // Will encrypt better at a later point
$_SESSION['paypal_hash'] = $hash;

//Prepare and execute transacting storage
$store = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO transactions_paypal (user_id, payment_id, hash, complete) VALUES (:user_id, :payment_id, :hash, 0)
    ");

$store->execute([
    'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
    'payment_id' => $payment->getId(),
    'hash' => $hash
]);
header('Location: ' . $paypal_url); // the url where the user pays via a paypal.com site
```

After this code is executed, the user is redirected to pay.php:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); // This returns an empty array
$paymentId = $db->prepare("
    SELECT payment_id
    FROM transactions_paypal
    WHERE hash = :hash
    ");
$paymentId->execute([
    'hash' => $_SESSION['paypal_hash']
]);
```

Hash is stored properly in the database but is not kept in the session after being redirected back from PayPal.

Comment: Verify that the domain is exactly the same when returning.. ie. if you start from https://www.myDomain and paypal redirects to https://myDomain. Cookies are domain specific unless specified that they are wildcarded for subdomains.

Comment: Is it exactly the same url? What about domain.com and www.domain.com?

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly my issue. One file had https:// and one file had https://www. That solved it!

Comment: I don't believe the payment id needs to be secret. You shouldn't have to hash it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, shortly after some helpful comments, I found out that some files had put https:// and some files https://www. - Changing it to the same solved the issue.